# eXist-db change database files location

Tags: configuration, wildfly, exist-db

I am running eXist-db in servlet mode deployed on an WildFly 10 application server. But after redeploying the eXist-db WAR-file, all stored data is gone. So I want to change the path where the database data is stored. Currently it should be stored in "standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/..." but this dir is deleted on undeploying right?

Comment: Which version of eXist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eXist's default data directory is `$EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEB-INF/data`, but it can be  changed to a different directory, i.e., a directory outside the `$EXIST_HOME` directory, by editing `$EXIST_HOME/conf.xml` under `db-connection/@files`. See the eXist documentation about the `conf.xml` configuration file here: https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/configuration.xml#D2.2.4.6

Comment: You should probably also change `recovery/@journal-dir`

Comment: Thx a lot. I read this section but I did not notice it ... Just downloaded the current development state and builded the war. Works like a charm!

Comment: Great, glad to hear!